# How to find duplicate names using pandas?

Tags: python, group-by, pandas

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` with a column called `name` containing strings.
I would like to get a list of the names which occur more than once in the column. How do I do that?

I tried:

```
funcs_groups = funcs.groupby(funcs.name)
funcs_groups[(funcs_groups.count().name>1)]
```

But it doesn't filter out the singleton names.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you want to find the rows with duplicated name (except the first time we see that), you can try this

```
In [16]: import pandas as pd
In [17]: p1 = {'name': 'willy', 'age': 10}
In [18]: p2 = {'name': 'willy', 'age': 11}
In [19]: p3 = {'name': 'zoe', 'age': 10}
In [20]: df = pd.DataFrame([p1, p2, p3])

In [21]: df
Out[21]: 
   age   name
0   10  willy
1   11  willy
2   10    zoe

In [22]: df.duplicated('name')
Out[22]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
```

Comment: I like this better than mine.

Answer (score 11):

A one liner can be:

```
x.set_index('name').index.get_duplicates()
```

the index contains a method for finding duplicates, columns does not seem to have a similar method..

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  Thanks @idoda!

Comment: Does this "set_index()" destroy the indexing of the original dataframe called x? Should I run this command on a copy of the dataframe?

Comment: note that `index.get_duplicates()` is [deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Index.get_duplicates.html) since `v0.23`

Answer (score 8):

[value_counts](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) will give you the number of duplicates as well.

```
names = df.name.value_counts()
names[names > 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Most of the responses given demonstrate how to remove the duplicates, not find them.

The following will select *each* row in the data frame with a duplicate `'name'` field. Note that this will find *each* instance, not just duplicates after the first occurrence. The `keep` argument accepts additional values that can exclude either the first or last occurrence.

```
df[df.duplicated(['name'], keep=False)]
```

The pandas reference for `duplicated()` can be found [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html).

Answer (score 2):

Another one liner can be:

```
(df.name).drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and came across this answer.

I guess this also works:

```
counts = df.groupby('name').size()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(counts, columns = ['size'])
df2 = df2[df2.size>1]
```

and `df2.index` will give you a list of names with duplicates

Comment: Better to use df2['size'] instead of df2.size as df2.size is a built-in function.